# define manually the position of a pgfplots plot inside the TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, matlab2tikz

I just started using `matlab2tikz` for the graphics in my thesis and got stuck with a probably simple problem: I have a plot of a function and an inset (zoom-in) on it. Both the main plot and the inset are aligned to the origin, so that the axis overlap. I need a way to define the position of the inset manually. Here is the code for the inset:

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=2.1cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.6235,
xmax=-0.6186,
xtick={-0.623, -0.621, -0.619},
ymin=0.1651,
ymax=0.1655,
ytick={0.1651, 0.1653, 0.1655},
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-0.6236 0.165085    \\
-0.6232 0.165117    \\
-0.6228 0.165149    \\
-0.6224 0.165181    \\
-0.622  0.165212    \\
-0.6216 0.165244    \\
-0.6212 0.165276    \\
-0.6208 0.165308    \\
-0.6204 0.16534 \\
-0.62   0.165372    \\
-0.6196 0.165404    \\
-0.6192 0.165436    \\
-0.6188 0.165468    \\
-0.6184 0.1655  \\
};
\end{axis}
```

I tried to add something like:

```
pos={at={(1.5,0.6)}, anchor=north west}
```

but it does not work. Can't find any solution in the pgf-manual, so hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It sounds like you might want `axis cs`

Comment: You need to look at [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) manual not at [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf)

Answer (score 7):

One option: the inset is saved in a box and then placed at the desired position using a `\node` and the axis coordinate system for the main plot (See Section **4.17.1 Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements**):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

% the box is filled with the inset
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=2.1cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.6235,
xmax=-0.6186,
xtick={-0.623, -0.621, -0.619},
ymin=0.1651,
ymax=0.1655,
ytick={0.1651, 0.1653, 0.1655},
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr] {
-0.6236 0.165085    \\
-0.6232 0.165117    \\
-0.6228 0.165149    \\
-0.6224 0.165181    \\
-0.622  0.165212    \\
-0.6216 0.165244    \\
-0.6212 0.165276    \\
-0.6208 0.165308    \\
-0.6204 0.16534 \\
-0.62   0.165372    \\
-0.6196 0.165404    \\
-0.6192 0.165436    \\
-0.6188 0.165468    \\
-0.6184 0.1655  \\
};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% the main plot; a \node is used to place the inset
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=9cm,
height=7cm,
scale only axis,
]
\addplot [color=red,forget plot]
coordinates { (0,0) (1,3) (2,1) (3,-1) (4,3) (5,5) (6,6) (10,10)};
\node at (axis cs:8,2) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is **savebox** a pgf specific command or standard LaTeX? Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

this can be done without saveboxes, too. Just put the axis in the same tikzpicture and shift it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=9cm,
height=7cm,
scale only axis,
]
\addplot [color=red,forget plot]
coordinates { (0,0) (1,3) (2,1) (3,-1) (4,3) (5,5) (6,6) (10,10)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=2.1cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.6235,
xmax=-0.6186,
xtick={-0.623, -0.621, -0.619},
ymin=0.1651,
ymax=0.1655,
ytick={0.1651, 0.1653, 0.1655},
xshift=5.25cm,yshift=0.75cm % <-
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr] {
    -0.6236 0.165085    \\
    -0.6232 0.165117    \\
    -0.6228 0.165149    \\
    -0.6224 0.165181    \\
    -0.622  0.165212    \\
    -0.6216 0.165244    \\
    -0.6212 0.165276    \\
    -0.6208 0.165308    \\
    -0.6204 0.16534 \\
    -0.62   0.165372    \\
    -0.6196 0.165404    \\
    -0.6192 0.165436    \\
    -0.6188 0.165468    \\
    -0.6184 0.1655  \\
};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`xshift=5.25cm,yshift=0.75cm` is the key to success here.

[image: result]